# I need help with a broken LEGO motor

Tags: motor, repair

I have a LEGO motor and it broke but I didn't know why so I took apart the LEGO motor to see if the wires were the problem.  I tested the wires to see if they were working but they weren't and I can't find where they are broken so any advice on what I should do?

Comment: What type of LEGO motor do you have? Also, what do you mean by 'it broke'?  Does it turn slowly or not at all? Can you turn it by hand?

Comment: PF large motor.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution, provided that motor is still in production, is to contact the [LEGO customer service](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service) using the "broken part" button, or via telephone directly which might be easier for a part such as a motor.

They'll usually provide a replacement without problem, but be advised that by opening the motor yourself, you probably voided any sort of warranty and may need to pay for a replacement.

Comment: Hi your link is not working for the form. I also have a a motor (large) thats not working

Comment: Indeed, LEGO changed their website a while ago, which means the link I provided isn't working anymore. Try https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service instead.